# What is the best practice to add a mandatory mark on sap.m.Input?

Tags: sapui5

[My Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/m123F7gV2orA0uOhFtLy?p=preview)

I know that `sap.m.label` has `required="true"` property that can add a mandatory mark. But I am using Input in table which did not has a label.

So my solution is put the mark in a special column，Is there any better way?

---

Update:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qifky6plPEzFtlpyV2vb?p=preview

Try using `Hbox` to cut down one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal would be replace the first column header with below to have overall indication on the whole column

```
<Label text="column1" required = "true" tooltip = "required"/>
```

And with `liveChange` or `change` event handler of `Input`, you can set [ValueState](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ValueState.html) to `sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error` in case of empty value.

Comment: Thanks, but this mark is only used in the NEW item after click the `add` button. Update the demo here : http://plnkr.co/edit/yy3dNF4XSdwPq7xcsC0I?p=preview  And yes, I will use ValueState in `change` validation :)

Comment: Then you can add no "*" next to your input. Instead you can put (mandatory) in addition to your placeholder text. With you ValueState validation, I think you are fine.